# Não consigo utilizar funcão javascript no meu html

Tags: javascript, html, css, funções

Gostaria de ligar uma função para trabalhar com automatos finitos.

A intenção é que a partir dos form eu consiga trabalhar com ela
js:

```js
var ListaNo = new function () {
    this.Nos;

    function CriaNo(idNo){
        var NovoNo = new No(idNo);
        this.Nos.push(NovoNo);
        return NovoNo;
    }

    function AdicionaLigacao(idNo, termo)
    {
        var aux = buscaNo(idNo);
        if (aux == null) aux = CriaNo(idNo);
        aux.AdcionaNo(termo);
    }   


    function verificaGr(chave, nAtual, i){
        if(i<chave.length)
        {       
            var cAtual = chave[i];
            nAtual.terminal.foreach(element, index =>{
                if(element == cAtual)
                {
                    var NovNo = buscaNo(nAtual.variavel[index])
                    var aux;
                    if (NovNo != null)  aux = verificaGr(chave, NovNo, i+1);
                    else if (NovNo == null && i == chave.length-1)
                    {
                        if(nAtual.variavel[index] == 'λ') return true;
                    }
                    if (aux == true) return true;
                }
                else if (element == 'λ')
                {
                    var NovNo = buscaNo(nAtual.variavel[index])
                    var aux;
                    if (NovNo != null)  aux = verificaGr(chave, NovNo, i);
                    if (aux == true) return true;
                }
                return false;   
            }); 
        }
        else if(i == chave.length)
        {
            nAtual.terminal.foreach(element, index =>{
                if (element == 'λ' && nAtual.variavel[index] == 'λ') return true;
            });
        }
        else return false;
    }

    function buscaNo(idNo)
    {
        if(idNo == 'λ') return null;
        this.Nos.foreach(element, index =>{
        if(element.id == idNo)
        {
            return Nos[index];
        }   
    });
    return null;    
    }

    function LimpaNos()
{
    this.Nos = [];
}

    return{
        ListaNo, LimpaNos, buscaNo, verificaGr, AdicionaLigacao
};
}
```

html:

```html
<div class="cardGramatica">  
        <h4>Gramatica</h4>   

        <div class="Header" id="hd03">
            <form id="gramar">
                     Id
                    <input id="inputvar" maxlength="1"  style="width:5%" type="text" name="fname"><i class="fas fa-long-arrow-alt-right" style="font-size:15px; padding-left:5px"></i>
                    String
                    <input id="inputter" style="width:40%" type="text" name="fname">
                    <button type="button" style="width:100%" value="Adicionar" onclick="AdicionaLigacao(inputvar,inputter)" id="adicionar">Adicionar No</button>
            <br>
    </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Erro: [![Uncaught ReferenceError: AdicionaLigacao is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (index.html:59)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dl4OB.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dl4OB.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Existem varias maneiras de fazer isso, a maneira mais recomendada:
Primeiro você precisa selecionar o elementos da pagina no seu script, felizmente a Web APIs fornece essa funcionalidade nativamente com o querySelector, segue a sintaxe:
[`element = document.querySelector(selectors);`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)

No seu caso seria:

```js
$inputvar = document.querySelector("#inputvar");
$inputter = document.querySelector("#inputter");
$button = document.querySelector("button");
```

Depois disso você deve adicionar o evento ao botão, novamente a Web APIs nativamente fornece essa funcionalidade com addEventListener, segue a sintaxe:
[`alvo.addEventListener(type,listener\[, options\]);`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Element/addEventListener)

No seu caso seria:

```js
$botao.addEventListener('click', () => ListaNo.AdicionaLigacao($inputvar,$inputter));
```

Se você adicionou seu script a pagina como um modulo e realmente quer acessar a função apartir do seu HTML você só precisa adicionar **ListaNo** como um property do objeto **window**(`window.ListaNo = ListaNo;`), isso tornara o **ListaNo** visível no escopo global da pagina. Porem, por questões de boas praticas, é altamente recomendado que você faça da maneira recomendada anteriormente uma vez é sempre preferível deixar toda a lógica no JavaScript, assim como é preferível deixa toda a estilização no CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Vc esta tendo esse erro pq a function esta dentro de uma variavel.

Ao inves de chamar a funcao no html pelo onclick vc pode tentar chamar ela depois da variavel com isso.

```
document.getElementById('adicionar').onclick = function(){
    ListaNo.AdicionaLigacao('inputvar','inputter');
}
```

Vai ficar parecido com isso 
https://jsfiddle.net/rfom0735/1/

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta e pela ajuda Fábio, no exemplo funcionou, porém agora deu o seguinte erro: ListaNo.js:75 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null
    at ListaNo.js:75

Comment: A intenção do código é que a cada entrada de nó eu possa coloca-los na lista e depois verificar se a gramática está correta

Comment: Tenta botar o script antes do </body>. Acho que ai vc nao vai mais ter esse erro.

Answer (score 0):

Obrigado pela respostas, consegui resolver utilizando o método do Fabio e um arquivo js auxiliar para manipular as funções.